# definition of complete vector lattice

Tags: definition, von-neumann-algebras, vector-lattices

Suppose $M$ is a von-Neumann algebra, $L=M\cap M'$ is the centre of $M$. The last line on page 29, *C*-algebras and their automorphism groups*, states that the self-adjoint part $L_{sa}$ of $L$ is a complete vector lattice.

Found in wekipeida, a *complete* lattice is a lattice in which each subset have both a supremum and a infimum.

However, even for $M=\mathbb{C}$, $L_{sa}=\mathbb{R}$ is not complete according to the above definition, as $\mathbb{R}$ itself has neither  supremum or infimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $(\Bbb R, \min, \max)$ is indeed not a complete lattice, but it is *almost* complete: $\bar{\Bbb R}:=\Bbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\} $ is complete, or put in other words,

> Every *bounded above* subset has maximum.

which implies that every bounded below subset has minimum.

And actually this is the definition of *(Dedekind) completeness* for vector lattices, cf. [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_space).